# How to remove transform from svg?

Tags: javascript

So I have `const svg = e.target.parentElement;` (targeting the inline svg and its surrounding div (so `<div><svg><path transform="rotate()"/></svg></div>`)), I then have `${svg.outerHTML}` in a `result.innerHTML =` but when the svg gets in the innerHTML (only in innerHTML) I want it to remove the `transform="rotate()"`from the inline svg.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let pathTransform = document.getElementById('YOUR_SVG_ID').childNodes[0].transform;
```

This Will return the SVGAnimatedTransformList object which has 2 properties:

1. baseVal: the original value of your transformations (rotate,
   translate...). I.e. the value you used in your HTML.
2. animVal: the
   current animated value of the given attribute

You have one transform in your path (rotate), to access it:

```
let rotateTransform = pathTransform.baseVal[0];
```

rotateTransform works with any of the SVGTransform methods listed here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SVGTransform

So to set the rotate to 0:

```
rotateTransform.setRotate(0, 0, 0);
```

Three zeros because we need to provide the numbers: in float angle, in float cx, and in float cy.

---

Now, what if you want to use more than one transform in your path? Or you want to add and remove transforms programatically. In that case, you can use the type property in order to identify your transforms. For example, rotate is type 4. So if we loop over baseVal:

```
for (const transform of document.getElementById('YOUR_SVG_ID').childNodes[0].transform.baseVal) {
    if (transform.type === 4) transform.setRotate(0, 0, 0);
}
```

Whenever the loop finds a rotate, it will set it to 0.

You can also remove the rotate completely by calling the removeItem(i) method on baseVal since baseVal is a SVGTransformList. In fact, you can call any of the methods mentioned here on baseVal:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SVGTransformList

```
document.getElementById('YOUR_SVG_ID').childNodes[0].transform.baseVal.removeItem(i);
```

Comment: How would I tell it to target the svg path of the const svg?

Comment: I've updated the answer. Skip to the last line i wrote in case you think this is too complicated; just use 0 instead of i.